# App Store Links

Tags: iphone, hyperlink

Hey all. Im using the following string in the "[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]" function to access the app store app and make a predefined search in the app store on a button press in my app.

@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?term=[MY APP NAME]&media=software

This works great if the app store app wasn't closed on a (lets say) search detail page (dont know what the real term is for the page after a user has selected a search result )

If the App Store application opens on this page my search doesn't happen.

So I need to know if there is something I can add to force the app store app back to the search page or anything other than the search detail page so I can perform my search?

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to just use a direct link to your app by ID?  I've found that to work more reliably...

Comment: Yeh it's because it's not just one app. its a suite of apps or all our apps that would come up with our company name as the search term..

Answer (score 2):

http://itunes.com/apps/[MY APP NAME]